# Math symbols in text mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, best-practices

I need to write a text which contains some math symbols. In detail those include `\rightarrow`, `\forall` and `\exists`. I know I can switch into math mode with the `$` symbol, but I have quite a lot of text and I do not want em in italic like it is default for math mode.

I am just curious what is the right way to go. Shall I switch to math mode for every symbol and try to make the math mode "non-italic" or is there a better way like with the Greek symbols the `\textalpha`, etc. from the textgreek package?

Here is an example line from my text:

```
(S.Sname, B.Bname): ∀S ∃A ∃B (S.AId = A.AId \& B.BId = A.BId \& S.Sduration > 300)
```

Comment: If you use `XeLaTeX` and a font that contains these symbols (`DejaVu Sans`, for instance), you can compile as is.

Comment: @lenxn you can use `\text` command into equatios for comments or words. That text not appears in italic. Example: `$\forall x,\;\exists y\text{ such that }$`. I don't remember if you will need `amsmath` to use that command.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want not to be italic. Could you please provide a compilable example and say what you want to be different? The symbols you mention are not italicised, are they? (And nothing in maths mode is `\em` or `\emph`, if 'em' is not a typo for 'them'.)

Answer (score 5):

You could use this little snippet which defines `\textify`.  The control sequence `\textify` takes another control sequence (for instance `\exists`) and wraps it into `\ensuremath{…}`.

I don't think that one needs to go through all the `\GlobalLetLtxMacro` and `\protected\gdef` hassle for simple things like `\exists`, which is only a `\mathchar`, but this should cover all weird edge cases.

N.B.: The `\macro` in `\textify\macro` may not take any mandatory arguments.  Optional arguments will output as their default value.  If the macro you want to textify needs any arguments a more complicated approach is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\newcommand\textify[1]{%
  \expandafter\GlobalLetLtxMacro\csname textify@\string#1\endcsname#1%
  \protected\gdef#1{\ensuremath{\csname textify@\string#1\endcsname}}%
}

\textify\exists
\textify\forall
\begin{document}
\exists $\exists$

\forall $\forall$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

For reference, a non-`letltxmacro` and non-protected version of `\textify` would read

```
\newcommand\textify[1]{%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname textify@\string#1\endcsname#1%
  \gdef#1{\ensuremath{\csname textify@\string#1\endcsname}}%
}
```

which of course doesn't require the `letltxmacro` package.

Answer (score 0):

Redefine each of the symbols with `\ensuremath` so they always use math mode. To avoid an infinite `\ensuremath{\ensuremath{\ensuremath...` loop, save the old command with `\let` to use it in the new definition.

For example, to redefine `\to` (it's the same symbol as `\rightarrow`):

```
\let\OLDto\to
\renewcommand{\to}{\ensuremath{\OLDto}}
```

Now you can use `\to` in text mode! Read more [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-patch.html). Write `\to\` if you want the following space to not be eaten.

Comment: Basically, it is the same approach as in Henri Menke's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249635/16967). However, I would use a "better let" as provided by package `1etltxmacro`. Quite some math symbols are defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` (e.g. `\notin`, `\Longrightarrow`). Then, saving the old meaning in a new macro is more complicate, because *two* commands needs to be redefined to avoid trouble in some contexts.